# Retrieving sequences from fasta in order

Tags: python

I have a list of sequence IDs, like

```
Bob
Sara
Jess
```

and a fasta formatted file that contain all this sequences. I would like to retrieve them from the fasta file in the same order as in the list. The script below writes the sequence as soon as it sees it in the file, so it is not in the same exact order as in the list. Could you suggest how to change it to retrieve seq-s in order?

```
from Bio import SeqIO
setA=set()
f1=open('my_list.csv','r')
lines=f1.readlines()
for line in lines:# transcripts
    listA = line.rstrip('\n').split()
    setA.add(listA[0])

input_file = open('all_cds.fa','r')
output_file = open('my_cds.fa','a')
line_width = 60
for key in SeqIO.parse(input_file, 'fasta'):
    contig_name = key.name
    if key.name in setA:
        output_file.write(str('>' + (key.id)) + '\n')
        for i in xrange(0,len(key.seq),line_width):
            output_file.write(str(key.seq[i:i+line_width]) + '\n')
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Comment: For code improvements, ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am not asking how to improve it to look better, but how to improve it to retrieve seq-s in order.

Comment: You should provide a minimal example without unnecessary information. For example, I guess that lines 2 to 7 could be replaced with `setA = set(['Bob', 'Sara', 'Jess'])`

Comment: OK, but if the list if long, it is not very comfortable to write it all....

Comment: That's where *minimal* comes in. No need to write everything, just what is necessary for us to understand the problem